# Hook arbitrary function on to _exit(2)

Tags: c

I'm interested in whether I can call an arbitrary function on `_exit(2)` call, which bypasses other hooking architectures, so it doesn't seem easy to me.

- If this is an ordinary `exit(3)` or `return` statement, obviously it's possible by `atexit(3)`, `on_exit(3)`, or `__attribute__((destructor))` with gcc extension
- It is possible by overriding `_exit(2)` with `LD_PRELOAD`; which I wish to avoid

Is there a way to do it without `LD_PRELOAD`, say, overriding `_exit(2)`?

---

Edit: The problem I'm facing is `fork(2)`ed Perl programs with CoW. The program's children processes run destructors on `exit(3)` call, in which they touch many memory locations, to cause large memory copy, in spite they will exit.
It's hard to bypass destructors with ordinary `exit` call in Perl, so an idea is call `POSIX::_exit` instead.
However, there is a dynamically loaded library with `LD_PRELOAD`, and I want to call a function in it on process exit.

Comment: What's your outer problem? This may be an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).

Comment: Please improve your question by editing it to explain your motivations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIU, it is simply not possible without `LD_PRELOAD` tricks, or [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) with `PTRACE_SYSCALL`from *another* process (e.g. the parent process running `gdb`). At the lowest level, [_exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) is a [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) so is an "atomic" operation using the `SYSENTER` machine instruction, e.g. thru [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html).

Notice that a C program could use some `asm` to invoke the `_exit` syscall (or use the indirect [syscall(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html))

Assuming a dynamically linked executable to GNU libc or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/), your only way is to catch [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) library function (*not* the `_exit(2)` syscall!) using [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html)

You could redefine `_exit` and hope that the dynamic linker would call your `_exit`, not the one in `libc`. I won't play such tricks.

Alternatively, write a small wrapping C program which `fork`, `execve` and `waitpid` the original program.

Answer (score 0):

could you make use of the 'atexit()' function call?

Near the beginning of main() call atexit() with a parameter of the function that you want executed when the program exits.

You can call atexit() numerous time, thereby stacking several things to be executed when the application exits.

Comment: No. As I wrote `atexit` cannot hook `_exit`.

Comment: that seems like a very good reason to NOT use _exit().  Especially as _exit() terminates the calling process 'immediately' with no further exit processing.  you can fix the problem by using 'exit()' rather than '_exit()'.  In other words, your writing the code, so you get to decide what code/system functions to execute.